# Can groundhog burrows damage a pier foundation?

Tags: foundation

We have an addition to the house (a sunroom) that is built on a pier foundation. Recently, a groundhog has burrowed under it. Can the burrow damage the stability of the room, given that it's over a pier foundation?

[image]

Comment: Foundations are suppose to be on stable undisturbed ground.  A ground hog burrowing under foundations messes that up.  Pier foundations because of their smaller size are worst.  If not under the foundation, then not much of a problem.  Name it digger and make a tv/youtube show about him/her.  Sorry I think there is a youtube ground hog star, too late.

Comment: Can it? Yes. Is yours? We don't know without a lot more detail. Please [edit] to provide pics and maybe a drawing (with dimensions) and showing where the burrow is in relation to the piers.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a rough sketch.

Comment: You've got bigger problems: that's not a groundhog, it's a bear. (Just kidding, of course; I like the drawing)

Comment: Haha, my primitive drawings!